# Dict union and sum another field

Tags: python, django, dictionary

So, I have 2 dict and need sum t fields where username duplicated and transform in unique dict by username, but I don't know how do it.
Someone help me? I'm very confuse.

```
{username:'unique_username', t:20}
{username:'unique_username_2', t:13}
{username:'unique_username', t:20}
{username:'unique_username_2', t:11}
```

I need return like this

```
{username:'unique_username', t:40}
{username:'unique_username_2', t:33}
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Are these dicts in a list?

Comment: Yep, I forgot put: [{objects}, {objects} ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to aggregate the summary totals, then loop over that summary to build the desired dictionaries:

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> maps = [
    {'username': 'unique_username', 't': 20},
    {'username': 'unique_username_2', 't': 13},
    {'username': 'unique_username', 't': 20},
    {'username': 'unique_username_2', 't': 11},
]

>>> summary = Counter()
>>> for m in maps:
        summary[m['username']] += m['t']

>>> [{'username': uun, 't': total} for uun, total in summary.items()]
[{'username': 'unique_username_2', 't': 24}, {'username': 'unique_username', 't': 40}]
```